# Strange layout of my textview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

On my view I want a small piece of space reserved for a title. Beneath that there must be a textview filling the remaining space. This is how my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_titel"
        style="@style/DetailTextTitel" 
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="@style/DetailTextText" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_weight="1.9"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However this makes my "text1" Textview center in the middle of the screen with a very small width. 
My app contains a lot of different layouts (text and image, or 2 images and a small text, one big image) which can be viewed and all work fine except this one. Can someone spot the problem in my layout?

**EDIT**
This are the defined styles for DetailTextTitel and DetailTextText:

```
<style name="DetailTextTitel">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#28465a</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DetailTextText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#28465a</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

**EDIT** 
also added a screenshot:

[image: Title with Text]

Comment: Change `text1`'s width to `match_parent`...?

Comment: Oh sorry tried that still the same. Ill upload an screenshot of my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out I was inflating the wrong layout -_-.. Thats what happens when your app contains 50+ different layouts.

However thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing these attributes for textview with id text_titel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
android:layout_marginRight="10sp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text_titel"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="DetailTextTitel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#28465a"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"

    android:text="DetailTextText"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="#28465a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:layout_weight="1.9"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't I defined those in my style?

Comment: @MarkMolina i just defined all the attributes in textview and attached a snap shot of the same. check. make the text size of 1st textview also 10sp

Comment: Hmm I added your code to my layout but it's still the same. Guess the problem isn't in this layout then but thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will fix your problem (with Android layouts it's always been a bit of trial and error for me). However why don't you try:

- Assigning height as 0dp to the upper text view
- Checking that the referenced styles do not contain properties that will mess with the representation of the views referencing them
- Uploading a screenshot

**Edit**

- Try removing the height definition from the styles (if they apply to
  this layout only! - otherwise create new styles)
- Try either removing the width definition from the styles (same pre-condition) or from the text views